# TextView setText appearing to interfere with dragging Button with MotionEvent

Tags: android, textview, motionevent

I have some strange behaviour here (looks strange to me anyway).

I have two buttons, dragging one left / right also moves the other. This works ok, until I use a setText to update a TextView with details of what event it's in. If the tv.setText lines below are uncommented, it seems to be causing the buttons to be set back to their original locations.

I'd greatly appreciate it if I'm doing something obviously silly and someone could let me know.

Thanks.

code here:

```
package com.kk.moveit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MoveIt extends Activity {

Button b1,b2;
TextView tv;

int b1X;
int wndwX; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_move_it);

    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b1.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // the view is pressed
                    b1X = (int) event.getX();
                    wndwX = (int) event.getRawX();
   //               tv.setText("ACTION_DOWN");
                    return false;
                //break;                        
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // a movement is applied to the view
                    int l0 = view.getLeft();
                    int l = (int) event.getRawX() - b1X;
                    int r = l + view.getWidth();
                    view.layout(l, view.getTop(), r, view.getBottom());
                    move(b2,l-l0);
  //            tv.setText("ACTION_MOVE");
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
 //                 tv.setText("ACTION_UP");
                    // the view is released
                    return true; // finished with this event
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
                    // something happened and the
                    // action was not completed
                    return true; // finished with this event
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE):
                    // action happened outside the bounds
                    // of the view
                    return true; // finished with this event    

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void move(View v, int l) {
    int l0 = v.getLeft();
    v.layout(l+l0, v.getTop(), l+l0+v.getWidth(), v.getBottom());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_move_it, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

and the xml here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MoveIt" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the tv.setText lines below are uncommented, it seems to be causing
>   the buttons to be set back to their original locations.

Setting the text on those `TextViews` will trigger a new measurement and layout of the view hierarchy. This new layout passes will cancel the changes you've done to those views positions(with the `layout()` method) because the `LinearLayout` has it's own layout mechanism which it uses to place its children.

If you want to implement dragging then you could use the SDK drag and drop framework(available with Honeycomb if I'm not mistaken) or change your current layout to use a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` root and change the `LayoutParams` of the views in the `onTouch` method.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Setting the width of the TextView to match parent works as well.